# Error occurred during initialization of VM due to java.nio.charset.IllegalCharsetNameException

Tags: java, android, jenkins, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am using gradle-2.5 version.
I am getting this error when I am trying to build an android project.

```
[abc_Android_App] $ /cip/opt/gradle-2.5/bin/gradle
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.nio.charset.IllegalCharsetNameException: 
at java.nio.charset.Charset.checkName(Charset.java:303)
at java.nio.charset.Charset.lookup2(Charset.java:484)
at java.nio.charset.Charset.lookup(Charset.java:464)
at java.nio.charset.Charset.defaultCharset(Charset.java:609)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.forOutputStreamWriter(StreamEncoder.java:56)
at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.<init>(OutputStreamWriter.java:111)
at java.io.PrintStream.<init>(PrintStream.java:104)
at java.io.PrintStream.<init>(PrintStream.java:151)
at java.lang.System.newPrintStream(System.java:1148)
at java.lang.System.initializeSystemClass(System.java:1192)

Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' marked build as failure
An attempt to send an e-mail to empty list of recipients, ignored.
Finished: FAILURE
```

I have searched in Google for similar kind of error and found this type of error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.nio.charset.IllegalCharsetNameException: UTF-8 -Xmx4G -Xms4G
```

which had a solution for it. 
But in my case, the error is not showing UTF-8 -Xmx4G -Xms4G , and due to which I am unable to guess where the issue lies.

Please help me to get around this error.

P.s ( There is no space issue on slave)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Haven't seen this yet. Do you have any source files that are not utf-8-encoded?

Comment: Are you specifying any charset in your `build.gradle` file?

Comment: No @jolta. We haven't specified any charset in that file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you dont have "\" [UTF-8] in the gradle.properties file like the below one.

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX\:MaxPermSize\=512m -XX\:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding\=UTF-8\
```

Correct one:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX\:MaxPermSize\=512m -XX\:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```